# How to fire custom link click event of Floodlight tagging ?

Tags: javascript, tagging, google-floodlight

I want to fire custom link click event of Floodlight tagging for counting number of click to that link.Please help.

Comment: ala vishla tu ahiya :D

Comment: Doesn't this got what you are looking for https://support.google.com/dfa/partner/answer/134533?hl=en

Comment: @Neel :what does that mean?

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda:Does it count the number of clicks on that perticular link